# WordPress site cannot be reached after installation in CPanel with Softaculous

Tags: wordpress, redirect, dns, cpanel, softaculous

I am really a beginner using **CPanel**, so please apologize for my ignorance.

I have my own domain name, let's call it victor.com.
I had successfully installed **WordPress** with a selected Theme using **Softaculous** through CPanel. In the end, it showed me the installation was successful, and I can reach my site using my domain (victor.com) and the admin site for editing my WordPress site using the admin domain (victor.com/blablabla).

But none of them works. I tried to manage my domain in CPanel by setting up the redirection, but after a few setups, nothing has changed.

What do I miss? I really would like to start my experience in WordPress, but I cannot proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You might be installing it in wrong directory.

Check image:

[image]

Comment: this is how I did exactly!